# Kafka Consumer: How to programatically consume from specific offset in Go Sarama

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, sarama

Recently, I began to study working with *kafka*. The project I'm working on uses *sarama*.

For reading messages I use `ConsumerGroup`.

I need to read the message again after some time if `foo` returns `false`. How can this be done?

```
func (consumer *Consumer) ConsumeClaim(session sarama.ConsumerGroupSession, claim sarama.ConsumerGroupClaim) error {

    for message := range claim.Messages() {

            if ok := foo(message); ok {
                session.MarkMessage(message, "")
            } else {
                // ???
            }

    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: You cannot. That is not how Kafka works. If you do not commit any more messages and restart you will be able to consume from the last commited offset. Probably the simplest thing is to to publish the message once more.

Comment: If I do not want to publish new messages, then to read the message again, will I have to create a new `ConsumeGroup` each time with a set  offset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reset the offset of a Consumer Group to an older offset by including the following in your Consumer Group's `Setup()` callback:

```
func (e myConsumerGroup) Setup(sess sarama.ConsumerGroupSession) error {
    sess.ResetOffset(topic, partition, offset, "")

    return nil
}
```

---

You can also achieve the same through console:

```
kafka-consumer-groups \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
    --group my-consumer-group \
    --topic myTopicName \
    --reset-offsets \
    --to-offfset 100 \
    --execute
```

Comment: To apply the offset change, where do I need to call the `Setup` method?

Comment: @rogatzkij That's a callback from your Consumer Group

Comment: It's called before creating a session. So I have to re-create the session using `consumerGroup.Consume` to move the offset. I understand correctly?

Comment: @rogatzkij yeap.